# What's meta-arithmetic?

Tags: reference-request, arithmetic, definition

I am not able to find a definition of meta-arithmetic. Thus I am asking here this

> **Question.** Do you know what's means meta-arithmetic? If do you know it, can you explain me in easy words what is the feasible/possible meaning of such definition for *meta-arithmetic*? **Many thanks.**

Feel free to add references if do you find it, to illustrate your explanation with examples or create an example with this purpose.

Comment: In geenral, see [Metamathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metamathematics) : "the study of mathematics itself using mathematical methods. This study produces metatheories, which are mathematical theories about other mathematical theories." So, unless specified otherwise (have some detailed reference to add to your post ?), it is the "logico-mathematical" sthudy of arithmetic theory.

Comment: Simple example of meta- problems : is the theory $T$ (e.g. *arithmetic*) *consistent* ? is it *complete* ?

Comment: *Yesterday I've invented* the word meta-arithmetic while I was thinking in a problem, thus I have no a reference to add to my post. When I've search in Google I don't find a definiton directly in it. Many thanks for your attention and help @MauroALLEGRANZA

Comment: Thanks, when I can I will go to a library of an university to read the more simple/introductory definition @MauroALLEGRANZA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, see [Metamathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metamathematics):

> "the study of mathematics itself using mathematical methods. This study produces metatheories, which are mathematical theories about other mathematical theories."

So, unless specified otherwise, it is the "logico-mathematical" study of arithmetic theory.

Some sources :

- Sthepen Cole Kleene, [Introduction to Metamathematics](https://books.google.it/books?id=HZAjPwAACAAJ) (1952)

and:

- Petr Hájek & Pavel Pudlák, [Metamathematics of first-order arithmetic](https://books.google.it/books?id=h_zuAAAAMAAJ) (1993).